iText 8 with pdfCalligraph doesn't correctly handle Arabic with some fonts
On using iText 8 with pdfCalligraph add-on, the Arabic characters are separated, which is incorrect.
Output:

Expected:
هذه هي الجملة المستخدمة في المثال


com.itextpdf:iText 8.0.5
com.itextpdf:typography   4.0.2
Font file was downloaded from here

A minimized sample take from the website, also including the hints in the video:
Update: For some reason, changing the font to the one inside the typography.jar (NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf) seems to work, but I am not sure why Naskh font doesn't work.
 class Abc {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(new File("path to license.json"));

    try (var writer = new PdfWriter("out.pdf");
         var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
         var document = new Document(pdfDocument)) {
      var font_path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(
          "NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf");

      PdfFontFactory.register(font_path.toString());
      System.out.println(PdfFontFactory.getRegisteredFonts());
      var font = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont("noto naskh arabic", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

      var paragraph = new Paragraph()
          .setFont(font)
          .setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
          .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
      paragraph.add("هذه هي الجملة المستخدمة في المثال");
      document.add(paragraph);
    }
  }
}

